# Partial search with solr

Tags: apache, solr

I use Apache Solr with Drupal. The problem is that it match exact word.

Example : search 'Hello' will return  just the word Hello and not another word that begin with hello.

How can I configure Apache Solr to search partial word ?

Cordially

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use [wildcard queries](http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/) e.g. hello*
This would either client to either enter the query in this format or modifying it in the application.

Also you need to take into account :-

[#Analyzers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers) mentions -

> On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the
>   search word

Else, you can generate tokens using [solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) and this would match the records. e.g. hello would generate he, hel, hell, hello and hence would match all these combination.

Comment: It is important to clarify that when using wildcard queries, q=hello* would return "hello", "Hello", and "helloworld".  However, q=Hello* would return only "Hello" from the list above.  Adding any capital letter to a wildcard search string makes the query case sensitive.